# Javascript Performance in Node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I have code in a module which looks something like this:

```
var MyModule = module.exports;

MyModule.some_function = function(arg) {
    // Do some code here
    // Do some logging using the function name
    // var function_name = calleeArgs.callee.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1];
    // BAD, this method doesnt have a name
};
```

The code above does not work as the function does not have a name.
As an alternative, I could do the following, in which case the log would contain the method name:

```
function _some_function(arg) {
    // Do some code here
    // Do some logging using the function name - BAD, this method doesnt have a name
    // var function_name = calleeArgs.callee.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1];
    // GOO, this method doesnt have a name
}

MyModule.some_function = function(arg) {
    _some_function(arg);
};
```

So my question is:

1.) Does this way of writing make any sense - as far as I understand _some_function() is local to this module so there will be no negative implications as far as global scope/access is concerned

2.) Does this (the second option) have any performance implications? (my guess would of course be no, or at least relatively negligible)?

Comment: You can use named function expressions in JS. And with Node, you don't even have to worry about an IE bug with that stuff.

Comment: No need to wrap it - you can use either: `MyModule.some_function = _some_function;` in the second case or `MyModule.some_function = function some_function(...) {}` in the first case.

Comment: Thanks! The obvious solution - not used to Javascript syntax...

Answer (score 0):

1) I find that code style very confusing and bloated. I think the following is the cleanest approach:

```
function some_function(arg) {
    // Do some code here
    // Do some logging using the function name
}

// Put exports at the end
exports.some_function = some_function;
```

2) A function wrapping another function will add a negligible overhead, but it should be avoided if it adds no value.

Comment: I agree it is not good though this is what one has in a non-JS world. Learning the best practices of this language takes a minor switch in thought process :-)